# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `item` where `barcode` = A002 and `id` <> 12)

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I try to update my table `Item` but I use unique validation in my controller, I have set the primary key = 'item_id' in my model but I keep get this error said unknown column id even though I have set the primary key as item_id in my model, when I try to use validation :

```
 // 'barcode' => 'unique:item' //
```

This error doesn't appear and the program works but in the unique of barcode it is checking itself for the unique column and it fails but seeing its own field. that's why i change my validation become this :

```
// 'barcode' => 'unique:item,barcode,'.$item_id, //
```

when I try to update I get this error :

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `item` where `barcode` = A002 and `id` <> 12)

ItemController :

```
public function update(Request $request,$item_id)
    {
        $messages = [
            'unique' => 'Sorry this barcode already exist....',
        ];
        $this->validate($request,[
           'barcode' => 'unique:item,barcode,'.$item_id,
        ],$messages);
        $data = $request->except(['_token']);
        Item::where('item_id',$item_id)->update($data);
        return redirect('/item')->with('sukses','item successfully updated');
    }
```

this is my model
Item.php :

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'item';
    protected $primaryKey = 'item_id';
    protected $fillable = ['barcode','item_name','category_id','satuan_id','price'];

    public function category_r(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id','category_id');
    }
    public function satuan_r(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Satuan','satuan_id','satuan_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using custom primary key you should also add its name to the validation:

```
$this->validate($request,[
           'barcode' => 'unique:item,barcode,'.$item_id.',item_id'
        ],$messages);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique

Comment: thank you so much, your answer really save me and my college project T^T

Comment: Glad to help :) Since you are new to community - its a good practice when someone answer your question to accept it (check mark under the voting panel). That way he is awarded and helps others with similar issue to find faster the correct answer :) Good luck with your project.

Comment: oh i'm sorry because i'm still new in this community i thought i need to click the up button hahah but i just check the mark voting panel for you . thank you once again